# jpa query.getResultList() get stucked, with no error

Tags: jpa

I have a strange case, I have written a simple code to query DB in JPA2.0

everything seems good, but when the code hits query.getResultList();

it just gets stuck and does not respond, then glassfish server gets about 20% of CPU

and then nothing happens, also it does not generate any error or log.

what is wrong?

I am using glassfish, EclipseLink, NetBeans

this is my code:

```
public List<?> getData(EntityManager em,Class entityClass){
Query query=em.createQuery("select entity from tblPromotions entity");
return query.getResultList();
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging it, where is it stuck? (kill or ctrl c to print the stack trace, or use a debugger)

Also turn logging on finest.

It could be a database lock, since it is a read, you must be using some sort of serialized transaction isolation, which is probably a bad idea.

How amy objects are in the table, it could just be taking a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

In My case After debugging into Hibernate i found that the query just returned too many rows for it to handle. 
so it is solved by setting some value for Max Results:

```
query.setMaxResults(100);
```

btw: always in such scenarios try debugging into the framework , and it can give you the answer :>